# hyperspace of a complete uniform space need not be complete

Tags: general-topology, analysis, uniform-spaces

I want to know the counter example for: Hyperspace of an arbitrary complete uniform space need not be complete.

The hyperspace of a uniform space $(X,\mathscr D)$ is obtained by forming the set $\mathscr H$ of all non empty closed subsets of $X$ and taking as a base for a diagonal uniformity on $\mathscr H$, the collection of all sets of the form $\{(A,B): A$ is $D$-close to $B\}$, for $D$ in $\mathscr D$, where $A$ and $B$ are $D$-close iff $A\subset D[B]$ and $B\subset D[A]$.

I know that it is not true for metric spaces so I was trying an example of a uniform space which is not either separating or second countable. But I think for me uniform spaces are more difficult to deal with, especially the counter examples. 
It is an exercise 39D in the book "General topology",by Stephen Willard

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you mean by *hyperspace*.

Comment: @MartinSleziak By hyperspace, I mean the set of all non empty closed subsets of a uniform space X.

Comment: But this set can be endowed with various topologies. (For example Hausdorff metric, Wijsman topology - if the original space is a metric space - Vietoris topology and many other topologies.) Without specifying which metric/uniformity are you talking about, it does not make much sense to ask whether this space is complete. (Hausdorff metric and Vietoris topology are also mention in the Wikipedia article on [hyperspaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspace_%28topology%29).)

Comment: If you have seen the claim you're asking about in some paper or a book; citing the source would probably help potential answerers.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It is an exercise 39D in the book "General topology",by Stephen Willard.

Comment: Can't comment so here goes with an answer. An excellent reference is the recent "[Uniform spaces and Measures](http://books.google.com/books?id=Xtevbsc9Jc8C)" by Jan Pachl.

Comment: I have edited the math in your post (based on Willard's text), please, check whether I have not changed something unintentionally. Perhaps you could also include into your question the information that it is from Willard's book. (BTW Willard gives the following hint: Consider a complete space $X$ of cardinality $\mathfrak c$ whose (covering) uniformity is the uniformity having as a base all countable covers of $X$ (36B.5).)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).